# Android Activity setContentView

Tags: android

I am writing my first Android application. It is game-based, and I do all the drawing to a SurfaceView. My Activity does `setContentView(new mySurfaceView());` to start my activity with my SurfaceView displayed.

I would like the user to be able to input text and fill out forms. The forms will also allow input based on the original SurfaceView. I would like to be able to trigger an Android layout to display, be filled out, take the input and make the form disappear.

My first thought was to have a "stack" of views that my activity can push/pop, and I would push a new view onto the stack, display it, get what I needed from the view and then pop it off. However, I get an ANR in my main activity when calling `setContentView(newView);`. I'm looking for some help.

Do I really need to start a new activity for this, just to display a form to fill out? I want the user to be able to select items off of my original activity and use them in the completion of filling out the forms.

Basically, I'm stuck and need some design help from more experienced Android devs.